# Hack the virtual table of a C++ object without a reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio, virtual-functions, vtable

I know this question was asked here before but it is not exactly what I need, and as much as I try to manipulate the answers from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542108/how-to-hack-the-virtual-table) I cannot get the result I'm looking for.
So basically what I want to do is manipulate the virtual table in a C++ object so when calling one of the object's function it will call a different function
It is only for educational purposes of course.
my code is like that:

```
class Animal
{
private:
    int height;
    int length;
    int type;

public:
    virtual void makeNoise()
    {
    }

    virtual void sleep()
    {
    }
};
```

Dog inherits from Animal such as:

```
class Dog : public Animal
{
public:

    virtual void sleep() override
    {
        cout << "Going to sleep for Dog" << endl;
    }

    virtual void makeNoise() override
    {
        cout << "bark bark" << endl;
    }
};
```

Theres another class A:

```
class A
{
public:

    virtual void doSomething(void)
    {
        cout << "did nothing" << endl;
    }
};
```

The function Hack is the function I want to override A->doSomething()

```
void Hack()
{
   cout << "Hacked!" << endl;
}
```

main function:

```
void main()
{

   int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
   A* a = new A();
   Animal * dog = new Dog();

   someFunctionToManipulateVirtualTable(dog); //function get an object of type Dog but should hack into an object of type A's vtable

   a->doSomething(); //should print "Hacked!"

}
```

Now the question is what should I do here:

```
void someFunctionToManipulateVirtualTable(Animal * dog)
{ 
     //some code to manipulate main's local variable a (of type A).
}
```

So far, I have tried unsuccessfully , to get a's pointer through the dog reference from main, then get the virtual table pointer and override it with Hack's address, problem is , virtual table are in a read-only address location, I do manage to hack the vtable with local instances of A class, just with some pointer manipulation on the local instances..

Any lead on this will be awesome.
Thanks

Comment: Vtables are per-class, not per-instance; since the generated tables are read-only you need to build a compatible (complete) table and change each instance's vtable pointer. This is of course extremely platform-specific and undefined. (You won't ever access one object's vtable pointer through some other, unrelated, object, though.)

Comment: Nice, the hardware/system is preventing that intrusive hack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer molbdnilo, I'm not quite sure what you mean by building a complete table and change each instance pointer?  Should I read the current vtables and create new instances to overwrite the existing ones?

Comment: @LiorNaar: Obviously not. Overwriting a table doesn't create a new table.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to create the new vtable yourself first:

```
class Helper : A {
  virtual void doSomething() override { Hack(); }
}
```

Then create a `Helper` object, steal its vtable pointer, and put that vtable pointer in `a`.

Your solution assumes that the vtable for `Dog` is somehow related to the vtable of `A`. That's almost certainly not the case. The types are utterly unrelated.

Comment: There should be away to get to the vtable of a without the reference for it from a different function, I know it because the class I take is under how to create and how Compilers work so either from the heap or change it in a different way.. And what do you mean by steal it but then how can I put that pointer for a? It's in a read only area

Comment: @LiorNaar: You're mixing things up. `a` is an object, and does not have a vtable. It has a **pointer to** a vtable, in normal implementations. The table is read-only, the pointer is not. Can't be, because in derived classes the vtable pointer has to change as the different constructors execute. C++ has well-defined behavior for calling a virtual function during construction, and that's NOT calling overrides from base class constructors.

Comment: Ok now things are more clear, so you think I can just as said, steal the pointer from another A object I create in the MAGIC function and then make it point to a different vtable? Then I can just make it point to the function itself

Comment: It's easiest to see if we just pretend `a->_vptr` is the pointer to the vtable. I propose you create `Helper helper` and then do `a->_vptr = helper._vptr`. Note that I nowhere use `&Hack` or put that in a vtable. I'm using the fact that `Helper::vtable` contains `&Helper::doSomething` which ends up calling `Hack` directly. Far more reliable.

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer is not correct for this example.. im trying to "hack" the vtable by pointing the a function "Hack" that is unrealted to the classes mentioned above.. it should be independent, the way to do it, from a different function is to get the address of the function parameter that points to the same object that was created in "main" , then because we know in what order the objects were created we can find the other, "A* a" object that was created before "Dog *dog" in "main" and then change the vtable pointer there... thanks

Comment: @LiorNaar: No, that's a flawed assumption. The order of creation of objects is generally unrelated to their position in memory, _especially_ when they're not the same type/size.

Comment: In that specific case it is.. Well it doesn't matter how they were created in general but it does matter that you can get the address of Dog*dog that was created in main function to get to A*a and that is what is was looking for, now the question is how to write Hack method to that address is still ongoing.. The example I wrote was very specific so I'm looking for a very specific answer...

Comment: @LiorNaar: The chief problem is that objects of different sizes are often allocated from unique pools, each of which is individually allocated by the OS. No way to find a random object o\in one pool given another random object in another pool. (Clustering same-sized objects is a perfect strategy to avoid memory fragmentation)